# Command line tool written in rosperf_main.py cannot find `rosperf talker` executable

Tags: ros, roslib, package, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a rosperf package written in cpp, and runs alright using `rosrun rosperf talker`. Now I want to create rosperf command line tool (borrowed code from rosbag), but roslib.packages.find_node in rosperf_main.py cannot find the `rosperf talker` executable

How can I fix this? How to find the perf executable in python module?

This is the CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(rosperf)

if(NOT WIN32)
  set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "-g;-std=c++11;-Wall;-Wextra")
endif()

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS date_time thread)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS message_generation rostime roscpp rosconsole roscpp_serialization std_msgs)

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} include)
link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})

catkin_python_setup()

add_message_files(DIRECTORY msg FILES perf.msg)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

catkin_package(
    LIBRARIES rosperf
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime std_msgs
    )

macro(rosperf T)
  add_executable(${T} src/${T}/${T}.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(${T} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
  add_dependencies(${T} rosperf_gencpp)
  install(TARGETS ${T}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION})
endmacro()

foreach(dir
    perf_talker
    perf_listener
    )
  rosperf(${dir})
endforeach()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300145/command-line-tool-written-in-rosperf_main.py-cannot-find-%60rosperf-talker%60-executable/) by [foodtooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/36904/foodtooth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, this is typo in `roslib.packages.find_node` causing the error. I will add other info if the problem re-occurs.

---

Originally posted by [foodtooth](https://answers.ros.org/users/36904/foodtooth/) with karma: 16 on 2018-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0